# DecisionTreeClassifier fit method error (scikit learn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, scikit-image

Trying to train my *DecisionTreeClassifier* with `fit` method:

```
from sklearn import tree
import skimage

features = []
labels = []

for i in range(5):
    img = skimage.io.imread("circle" + str(i+1) + ".jpg")
    img = skimage.img_as_float(img)
    features.append(img)
    labels.append(0)

    img = skimage.io.imread("square" + str(i+1) + ".jpg")
    img = skimage.img_as_float(img)
    features.append(img)
    labels.append(1)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(features, labels)
```

Receiving error:

> **ValueError:** setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Perhaps related problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485503/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-while-using-svm-in-scikit), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51511432/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-in-scikit-learn-sklearn-u), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115472/sklearn-svm-fit-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence). Did you already have a look at all of them? Perhaps not

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548189/valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-with-decision-tree-where-al) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514019/setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence-error-while-training-svm-to-classify-im?rq=1) and several more

Comment: @Bazingaa I've seen this topic but the number of elements in both my lists are equal (10).

Comment: Perhaps there is some issue with the shape of the features? Try printing the shape by converting to numpy array

Comment: Bazingaa is probably right: `img` is likely a two-dimensional array. You can't use a two-dimensional array as a feature; try making it one-dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

You will use only the first pixel value alone, if you do the following.

```
features.append(img[0][0])
```

Try this!

```
import numpy as np
features.append(np.array(img).flatten())
```

please check the dimension of the data, which you are appending to know whats actually happening.

```
print(np.array(img).flatten().shape)
```

Comment: Decision tree might not be the best choice for image classification. try CNN.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, Bazinga and 9769953.

Solved my problem with replacing

```
features.append(img)
```

with

```
features.append(img[0][0])
```